# Reference for Understanding Shelah's Proof of Vaught's Conjecture for $\omega$-stable Theories

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

I'm looking for a source to help me better understand Shelah's proof of Vaught's Conjecture for $\omega$-stable Theories (https://shelah.logic.at/files/95409/158.pdf). An obvious candidate is Makkai's survey paper (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760649), but I felt it was pretty dense (and maybe I need to see a little bit more of motivation behind all the definitions).

So are there other sources that would enable me to understand the proof and maybe unpack things a little more than Makkai (or use a more modern exposition/viewpoint)? I feel that Baldwin's *Fundamentals of Stability Theory* could be good, but the more the better.

Cross-posted from [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790296/reference-for-understanding-shelahs-proof-of-vaughts-conjecture-for-omega-s).

Comment: Hopefully someone will come in with a reference but my impression is that there isn't a lot of good exposition of some of the more technical stuff in stability theory.